# How to Integrate PayUMoney BOLT with MVC4 c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, payumoney

Am trying to put a payment gateway in my project,All i need is to Pay on a button click.In the **PayUMoney** page i got a kit **ASP.NET BOLT** but it is not in MVC,I have knowlege only in MVC(am a newbie ).I have searched everywhere how to *integrate this with MVC4* but i dont get anything.
Kindly Help me with this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#payNowButton').on("click", function () {

              // Have these values in my page(which is needed for BOLT)

                    key: "VOu0fZrK",
                    salt: "rWgjocyTmL",
                    txnid: $('#orderid').val(),
                    amount: $('#grandtotal').val(),
                    fname: $('#fname').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(),
                    mobile: $('#phone').val(),
                    udf5: $('#udf5').val(),





    </script>
```

> Controller

```
public ActionResult Demo(Hash h)
        {

            //Code Which am seeking
        }
```

Dont have the idea about the controller

Comment: Do you want response data in `PlaceOrder();` ?

Comment: Actually this code is also i have copied somewhere from the google

Comment: What information do you want in your `Controller` ?

Comment: dont know how it is redirecting to PayUmoney page on a button click.Actually the controller may create some hash or something,dont know well about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved It and working Perfectly.I have created hash in the preceding page and store the hash into a session and display on the payment page,and did the following:
Added onclick function in Pay Button :

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    function launchBOLT() {
        alert($('#txnid').val() + $('#hash').val() + $('#grandtotal').val() + $('#fname').val() + $('#email').val() + $('#phone').val() + $('#oid').val() + $('#udf5').val() + $('#surl').val());
        bolt.launch({
            key: "Key Here",
            txnid: $('#txnid').val(),
            hash: $('#hash').val(),
            amount: $('#grandtotal').val(),
            firstname: $('#fname').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            phone: $('#phone').val(),
            productinfo: $('#oid').val(),
            udf5: $('#udf5').val(),
            surl: $('#surl').val(),
            furl: $('#surl').val()
        }, {
            responseHandler: function (BOLT) {
                console.log(BOLT.response.txnStatus);
                if (BOLT.response.txnStatus != 'CANCEL') {
                    //Salt is passd here for demo purpose only. For practical use keep salt at server side only.
                    var fr = '<form action=\"' + $('#surl').val() + '\" method=\"post\">' +
            '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"key\" value=\"' + BOLT.response.key + '\" />' +
            '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"salt\" value=\"' + $('#salt').val() + '\" />' +
            '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"txnid\" value=\"' + BOLT.response.txnid + '\" />' +
            '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"amount\" value=\"' + BOLT.response.amount + '\" />' +
            '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"productinfo\" value=\"' + BOLT.response.productinfo + '\" />' +
            '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"firstname\" value=\"' + BOLT.response.firstname + '\" />' +
            '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"email\" value=\"' + BOLT.response.email + '\" />' +
            '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"udf5\" value=\"' + BOLT.response.udf5 + '\" />' +
            '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"mihpayid\" value=\"' + BOLT.response.mihpayid + '\" />' +
            '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"status\" value=\"' + BOLT.response.status + '\" />' +
            '<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hash\" value=\"' + BOLT.response.hash + '\" />' +
            '</form>';
                    var form = jQuery(fr);
                    jQuery('body').append(form);
                    form.submit();
                }
            },
            catchException: function (BOLT) {
                alert(BOLT.message);
            }
        });
    }
    //--
</script>
```